# How can I create an option to filter out NULL values in a field?

Tags: looker-studio

I have used a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQ3QlHPJ7ySdjs4lXAky9QIWqQ6fVUZIMvRldZCXDWM/edit#gid=1850185094) to create a data source for a dashboard in Google Data Studio:

| Account_Number | Process_Date | Business_Unit | Budget_Reference | Vender_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000001 | 7/1/2017 | 113111 | 0 | ABCD Plumbing |
| 1000002 | 7/9/2017 | 114122 | 0 | ACME-1 Electric |
| 1000003 | 6/14/2017 | 114223 | 1 |  |
| 1000004 | 5/11/2017 | 112444 | 1 | Shark Industries |
| 1000005 | 5/12/2017 | 113334 | 2 | Cyberdyne Systems |
| 1000006 | 5/11/2017 | 114440 | 2 | Ollivander's Wand Shop |
| 1000007 | 5/9/2017 | 120001 | 2 |  |
| 1000008 | 5/17/2017 | 120009 | 2 | Wayne Enterprises |
| 1000009 | 4/4/2017 | 120005 | 3 | Fun City - USA |
| 1000010 | 4/15/2017 | 120014 | 3 |  |
| 1000011 | 3/11/2017 | 120111 | 3 |  |

I used it to build a [table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) and now want to use an [advanced filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335694) [control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) to filter out rows containing blank vendor names:

| Account_Number | Process_Date | Business_Unit | Budget_Reference | Vender_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000001 | 7/1/2017 | 113111 | 0 | ABCD Plumbing |
| 1000002 | 7/9/2017 | 114122 | 0 | ACME-1 Electric |
| 1000004 | 5/11/2017 | 112444 | 1 | Shark Industries |
| 1000005 | 5/12/2017 | 113334 | 2 | Cyberdyne Systems |
| 1000006 | 5/11/2017 | 114440 | 2 | Ollivander's Wand Shop |
| 1000008 | 5/17/2017 | 120009 | 2 | Wayne Enterprises |
| 1000009 | 4/4/2017 | 120005 | 3 | Fun City - USA |

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/95a784cd-68c8-4dca-ab67-47f9e93bdcb5):

[image: current]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either approach (1 **or** 2), based on the requirement:

1. ***Flexible*** - [Checkbox](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335390): Provides the **option** for users to switch NULL values on or off
2. ***Fixed*** - [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066): Use if the aim is to hide NULL values

## 1) Flexible: Control Box

To create a toggleable feature, a [checkbox](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335390) [control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) can be used, with the control field:

```
IF(Vendor_Name IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE)
```

The [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) above uses the [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770) function to detect NULL values in the `Vendor_Name` field, which then filters data based on the checkbox selection:

- ⊟: (Default) all data
- ☑: Data excluding NULL values
- ▢: Only NULL values

To view all data, click the ↶ [Reset](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#apr-15-2021) button on the report header.
Optionally, use [report links](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9266499) to ensure that users start with a default view:

- [NULL values excluded by default](https://datastudio.google.com/s/r8-6YVS3A2w)
- [Only NULL values shown by default](https://datastudio.google.com/s/rSAsyUSH6WM)

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e0ab09d8-bba6-4a74-aee6-464048cdfbe4) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SHsfOBZ36GqHnAqnMmNIepQKFi3Eoh9RbyfK-CYthpQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]

## 2) Fixed: Filter

To hide NULL values from users (without the ability for users to toggle), this [filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) would do:

[image: filter_exclude_null]

```
Exclude Vendor_Name is NULL
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/e0ab09d8-bba6-4a74-aee6-464048cdfbe4/page/p_8koevu23vc) ([Embedded Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SHsfOBZ36GqHnAqnMmNIepQKFi3Eoh9RbyfK-CYthpQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image: gif_v2]